# How to automatically reload a web page when having a certain variable's value?

Tags: python, html, cherrypy, page-refresh

In the following python/html script,I want to refresh the web page automatically when the value of the variable "condition" equal to "1". So that the page show me the new text contains of the variable "myText" automatically. The variable "myText" can have any text, and the following script is just an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cherrypy
import os.path
import struct
from auth import AuthController, require, member_of, name_is
import subprocess
import commands

class Server(object):
    led_logout=0 
    led_restart=0
    condition=0
    _cp_config = {
    'tools.sessions.on': True,
    'tools.auth.on': True
    }   
    auth = AuthController()      
    @cherrypy.expose
    @require()
    def index(self,logout=''):

    html = """
     <html>
      <head>
      </head>
          <body>
        <p>{htmlText} 
        <p>
            <a href="?logout=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?');"><img src="images/Logout.png"></a>
        </ul>
          </body>
     </html>    
           """
    myText = ''
    myText = "Hello"
    if logout:
        self.led_logout = int(logout)             
    if self.led_logout:
        print "Logout !!!!!"
        AuthController().logout('/?logout=0')         
    return html.format(htmlText=myText)      
    index.exposed = True
#configuration
conf = {
    'global' : { 
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0', #0.0.0.0 or specific IP
        'server.socket_port': 8085 #server port
    },

    '/images': { #images served as static files
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath('/home/ubuntu/webserver/images')
    }
    }
cherrypy.quickstart(Server(), config=conf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for you to get your text from the server you're going to need some ajax.

Give this a try...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cherrypy
import os.path
import struct
from auth import AuthController, require, member_of, name_is
import subprocess
import commands

class Server(object):
    led_logout=0 
    led_restart=0
    condition=0
    _cp_config = {
    'tools.sessions.on': True,
    'tools.auth.on': True

    auth = AuthController()
    @cherrypy.expose
    @require()
    def index(self):

    html = """
     <html>
      <head>
      </head>
          <body>
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       function getMyText()
       {
           // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
               xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
           else// code for IE6, IE5
               xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
           {
               if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
               {
                   document.getElementById('message').innerHTML= = xmlhttp.responseText;
               }
           }

           xmlhttp.open("GET","/getMyText?logout=True", true);
           xmlhttp.send();
       }
       </script>
        <p id="message"><p>
        <a href="?logout=1" onclick="return var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?');if (r==true){getMyText(condition);"><img src="images/Logout.png"></a>
        </ul>
          </body>
     </html>    
           """
    def getMyText(logout=False)
        myText = "Hello"
        if logout:
            self.led_logout = int(logout)
        if self.led_logout:
            print "Logout !!!!!"
            AuthController().logout('/?logout=0')
        return myText
    index.exposed = True

#configuration
conf = {
    'global' : { 
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0', #0.0.0.0 or specific IP
        'server.socket_port': 8085 #server port
    },

    '/images': { #images served as static files
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath('/home/ubuntu/webserver/images')
    }
    }
cherrypy.quickstart(Server(), config=conf)
```

Hope this helps!

Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the suggestion, I want to reload the page when the variable that has the name "condition" equal "1" only. I mean without clicking any button. however, when applaing your code I got:File "x.py", line 42, in index return html.format(htmlText=myText)  KeyError: 'location'

Comment: OK , may be the variable "condition" is not in the right place, this is just a variable which does not related to any button. This script is just example and the variable "condition" will related to another process. I assumed its initial value is zero, but it will be "1" when some condition will satisfy. sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Please refraise your question I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for trying to solve my problem even my question was not very clear. I am very beginner in both python and html, however I am very close to solve my problem and sorry for my previous bad question.

Comment: You're welcome.  I just finished my first cherrypy project and now I want to share what I learned.  Please let me know if I can be of any more help.